# Separation of AM and SZK

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, interactive-proofs

Are any results on the separation of AM from SZK known (e.g. relativized separation, or a separation assuming one-way functions exist, etc.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An oracle separation is easy to show. I'm not sure which paper showed it first, but for example you can already show that there exists an oracle $X$ such that

> $\mathsf{NP}^X \not\subset \mathsf{QSZK}^X,$

which implies

> $\mathsf{AM}^X \not\subset \mathsf{SZK}^X$

because $\mathsf{NP}$ is in $\mathsf{AM}$ and $\mathsf{SZK}$ is in $\mathsf{QSZK}$.
See [arXiv:1801.08967](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.08967) for one way to prove this. See the comment on page 3 of [arXiv:1902.03660](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.03660) for another way to show this.

Also note that in the unrelativized world $\mathsf{AM=SZK}$ would collapse the polynomial hierarchy, because $\mathsf{SZK}$ is closed under complement, and hence this implies $\mathsf{AM=coAM}$, which collapses $\mathsf{PH}$.